# Professionally breakdown the response from request

Tags: php, json, authorize.net

I don't want to use the SDK because it's overkill so I decided to create my own. I've managed to make it work but I'm having trouble to format the response nicely (make it a array or obj arr) so I can get the "resultCode".

this is the response for "authenticateTestRequest". I would like to get the value of "resultCode"

```
{
    "messages": {
        "resultCode": "Ok",
        "message": [
            {
                "code": "I00001",
                "text": "Successful."
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

response without custom pretty display

```
string(86) "{"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}"
```

json_decode and JSON Pretty Print is not working

my code (prints NULL if I put the json_decode):

```
function sc_test_authenticate( $api_endpoint, $login, $tran_key ) {     

    $params = array(
        'authenticateTestRequest' => array(
            'merchantAuthentication' => array(
                'name' => $login,
                'transactionKey' => $tran_key
            )
        )
    );

    $curl = curl_init();    

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $api_endpoint);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); 
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 300);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);  

    $response = curl_exec($curl);       

    curl_close($curl);  

    return json_decode($response);      
}
```

Comment: I used php cURL for the request

Comment: Is the first `}` a typo?

Comment: This example is not valid JSON (`} … }`) – that might be the reason why `json_decode` does not work.

Comment: can you submit the full json response.

Comment: yes it was typo. sorry

Comment: Seems to work fine then https://3v4l.org/lScjV

Comment: [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) works fine: https://3v4l.org/3ovlJ

Comment: If I print it it outputs NULL

Comment: If you print what? You haven't shown us any code to see what you're doing.

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Can't see anything obvious wrong there. What do you get if you `var_dump(json_decode($response));` before the `return`?

Comment: NULL, but if I remove the json_decode it displays the response but its like a string

Comment: See what [json_last_error](http://php.net/json_last_error) gives you after the `json_decode`.

Comment: string(86) "{"messages":{"resultCode":"Ok","message":[{"code":"I00001","text":"Successful."}]}}"

this is the response without json_decode

Comment: Looks like there might be some weird characters in there then since the string you've given is only 83 chars.

Comment: but that is the response from the request I sent to authorize

Comment: Did you try the json_last_error I mentioned above?

Comment: no error at all. I put it after the json_decode

Comment: It should have given you a number...

Comment: what does it mean? int(4)

Comment: That means there's a syntax error in the JSON, which does imply there may be invisible characters in there. Not sure there is any further help I can provide.

Comment: should I contact authorize? I did not manipulate any the response. I don't want to use the XML format